# How is Redis considered a CP system

Tags: redis, consistency, eventual-consistency

Redis uses by default asynchronous replication between master and slaves

Slaves replicate the data from the master and handle read operations only.

So there is always a window where Slaves do not have latest data and can serve stale data

This means Redis is AP and not CP ?

Comment: Redis, by *default*, doesn't replicate at all. That's optional; plenty of people run a single-instance Redis cache/store. You have a *choice* here; pick the one appropriate for your use case.

Comment: But having a single instance does not giving fault tolerance or high availability.

So if we have replication enabled - then Redis is AP or CP ?

Comment: Read https://redis.io/docs/management/replication/ and all the considerations there, pick a specific setup, and answer that question based on your knowledge.